# Extracting picture from rtf document

Tags: ms-word

I have rtf document in which is picture as the background. Problem is taht the file is 138MB and can't work with Oracle BI Publisherom Desktop. That software work with smaler - normal size of pictutures. My main problem is how to get picture from rtf file and than I can to resize it in something like acdsee. It apeears unposible to get that picture from the file. Printscrean is not an option.\
Thanks.

Comment: I recently discovered that picture that is in the document is Watermark. I need that watermark as image separately. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I successed to take picture from watermark. Just double click in the upper part of screen where is the header and chose save as.